# Terraform for loop with creating of multiply resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, for-loop, foreach, terraform, aws-glue

I have simple `glue job` in `aws`
This is an example:

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "myjob1" {
  name     = "myjob1"
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  command {
    name = "pythonshell"
    python_version = 3
    script_location = "s3://mybucket/myjob1/run.py"
  }
}
```

It is working, but if I have something like list `myjob1,myjob2,myjob3,myjob4,myjob5`. 
Could be, this esoteric example from bash:

```
listjobs="myjob1 myjob2 myjob3 myjob4 myjob5"

for i in ${listjobs}; do
resource "aws_glue_job" "$i" {
  name     = "$i"
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  command {
    name = "pythonshell"
    python_version = 3
    script_location = "s3://mybucket/$i/run.py"
  }
}
done
```

be real in terraform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this via `for loop`.
In `variables.tf`

```
variable "list_of_jobs" {
  default = ["myjob1","myjob2","myjob3"]
}
```

In `glue.tf`

```
resource "aws_glue_job" "this" {
  for_each = toset(var.list_of_jobs)
  name     = each.value
  role_arn = var.role_arn

  command {
    name = "pythonshell"
    python_version = 3
    script_location = "s3://mybucket/${each.value}/run.py"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your `listjobs` is:

```
variable "listjobs" {
  default = ["myjob1", "myjob2", "myjob3", "myjob4", "myjob5"]
}
```

then you can use [count](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#count-multiple-resource-instances-by-count) in terraform to create multiple `aws_glue_job`:

```
resource "aws_glue_job" {

  count = length(var.listjobs)  

  name     = var.listjobs[count.index]

  role_arn = var.role_arn

  command {
    name = "pythonshell"
    python_version = 3
    script_location = "s3://mybucket/${var.listjobs[count.index]}/run.py"
  }

}
```

Comment: Your answer is good, thanks You. But I resolved this via `for loop`, please look my post.